# How to Write a Regular Expression that allows only letters, numbers and special characters only i the middle never in the end

Tags: c#, regex, url

Need some regular expressions help.

So far I have my code working to allow a limited number of special characters.  However, I don't know how to get it to only allow them in the middle and never the end.

Can someone help me figure that part out?

Here is the code I am using in c#:

```
            Regex uRLToVal= new Regex("^[A-Za-z0-9-_.+!*]*$");

            if (!uRLToVal.IsMatch(this.mainURL))
            {
                results.AddPropertyError("Your Entry can only contain letters, numbers, underscores, periods, plus, exclamation marks and hypens. Special characters should always be inside numbers or letters.  Example: v!v is OK BUT NOT !vv or vv!");
            }
```

Comment: If the special characters must not occur in the end, what _should be_ in the end? (Also, which characters in your regular expression do you consider "special"?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9]+([-_.+!*]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$");
```

which means :

match must begin with at least one numeric or alpha char:`[A-Z-z0-9]+`

That sequence **may** be followed by zero or many special chars `-_.+!*` followed by at least one numeric or alpha char.
This second combination can happen zero or many times (example : `asdf-e*r!asdf`, or `a` are valid)

Comment: Correct, but the middle part should use `+` not `*`: `[-_.+!*]+`.  If there are no special chars, that part of the regex shouldn't even become active--that's what the outermost `*` is for.  Saying "zero or more" when you mean "one or more" just makes the regex engine work harder, for no purpose.

Comment: Thanks Alan  
Was this the final?
(@"^[A-Za-z0-9]+([-_.+!*]+[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$");