# javascript regular expression for textbox

Tags: javascript, regex

I want regular expression which accepts characters, numbers, special chars (only dot `.` and apostrophe `'` at the middle of the string not at the beginning and end of the string)

`^(\w|(\w(\w|'|\ )*\w))$`

Comment: and what you have tried so far?

Comment: write my regex expression for me... I don't want to

Comment: why should we write for you..

Comment: If you want to test only for characters from basic latin alphabet and want to exclude underscore character try `/^([a-z0-9]*|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.']*[a-z0-9])$/i`. Example: `(/^([a-z0-9]*|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.']*[a-z0-9])$/i).test(somestring)`

Comment: you can refer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928505/how-to-write-a-regular-expression-that-allows-only-letters-numbers-and-special

Comment: @user3269628 If you want to reply to a comment, use `@` + name to notify the user you are replying to. Otherwise it is hard to track the responses. Click the help button below Add Comment button when writing a comment.

Comment: This question would be better with some sample data showing what should and should not match.

Answer (score 2):

```
/^([^\.'].*[^\.'])$/
# http://rubular.com/r/Hpo03jntZi
# Test String:
# 'asdf..''.'##@$#@!$'
# .asdf..''.'##@$#@!$.
# .asdf..''.'##@$#@!$'
# 'asdf..''.'##@$#@!$.
# 'asdf..''.'##@$#@!$
# asdf..''.'##@$#@!$.
# asdf..''.'##@$#@!$
# Match Groups:
# 1. asdf..''.'##@$#@!$
```

http://rubular.com/r/Hpo03jntZi

Answer (score 1):

Use Below.

```
/^[^'.]+.*[^'.]+$/g
```